# Angular sort by json property with Angular Material md-select

Tags: angular, sorting, select, drop-down-menu, angular-material2

Not sure how to sort a list of returned json data with a md-select. Do I need a pipe? Or just a function in my component?

#### Returned json object

```
[ { name: 'repo-name', created_at: '2017-1-15T10:30:37Z', updated_at: '2017-1-16T11:30:30Z'}, {...} ]
```

#### repos.component.html

```
<!-- select with function if needed -->
<md-select placeholder="Sort by">
    <md-option *ngFor="let sort of sorts" [value]="sort.value"
      (click)="sortRepos( sort.value )">
      {{ sort.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>

<!-- repeater -->
<md-list-item *ngFor="let repo of repos ">...</md-list-item>
```

#### repos.component.ts

```
export class ReposComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
    repos: any[] = []; // populated via API call
    errorMessage: string;
    sorts: any[] = []; // for select options in constructor
    sortBy = 'created_at'; // set default sortBy

    constructor(private _repoService: ReposService ) {
        this.sorts = [
            { viewValue: 'newest', value: 'created_at' },
            { viewValue: 'updated', value: 'updated_at' },
            { viewValue: 'alphabetical', value: 'name' },
        ];
    }

    sortRepos( value ) {
        // ??? fails, doesn't seem like the right approach
        this.sortBy = value;
        this.sortBy === 'name' ? this.repos.sort( repo => repo.name )
        : this.sortBy === 'created_at' ? this.repos.sort( repo => repo.created_at )
        : this.repos.sort( repo => repo.updated_at );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._repoService.getRepos()
           .subscribe( repos => { this.repos = repos; 
           console.log(repos); },error => this.errorMessage = <any>error );
    }

    ngOnChanges() {}
}
```

Am I on the right track here? Or do I need a pipe that somehow gets into the .name, .created_at, and .updated_at and sorts according to that?

Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track but I would look into using Lodash as suggested by @Lazar.  I don't think you need a pipe for this.  The thing i notice is you're not assigning the sorted array back to the repos array anywhere in your code.  The call to `this.repos.sort()` returns a new array - it doesn't change the existing array.  You should be doing `this.repos = this.repos.sort(...)` for the sort to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom pipe or just write the logic in your component. Use the [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function from JavaScript. There is nothing special about Angular here, it is just your custom data transformation.

The sorting function accepts a comparison function which should return. `1`, `0` or `-1` based on the result of the comparison. The two arguments of this functions are two items of the array which are being compared.

The argument you're currently passing is suitable for [`sortBy` function from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy), so you might be interested in using that instead of the vanilla solution.

## `Array#sort`

```
const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)
```

## `_.sortBy`

```
const sortedArr = _.sortBy(arr, x => x.name)
```